# How to position ion-list inside component above everything else in screen

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to make an autocomplete component using Ionic basic components. I have achieved my desired result, however I am having a hard time positioning my list with suggestions above everything else in the screen. This bug happens:
[image: The suggestions get overriden by the textarea below]

I don't know how to solve this. Please help!
Here is my HTML and CSS:

```
<div #div>
  <ion-input
      #inputElem
      (ionInput)="handleInput($event)"
      (ionFocus)="handleFocus($event)"
      type="search">
  </ion-input>
  <ion-button (click)="showModalList()">
    <ion-icon name="list-outline"></ion-icon>
  </ion-button>
    <ion-list *ngIf="showList && suggestion$ | async as suggestions"
              [style.top.px]="div.getBoundingClientRect().y + div.getBoundingClientRect().height"
              [style.width.px]="div.offsetWidth" [style.maxHeight.px]="getMaxHeight(div)">
      <ion-item class="ion-text-wrap ion-padding-start ion-padding-end" button (click)="handleItemClick($event)"
                *ngFor="let suggestion of suggestions | autoCompleteFilter : currentValue">{{ suggestion.text }}</ion-item>
      <p class="ion-text-wrap ion-padding-start"
         *ngIf="(suggestions | autoCompleteFilter : currentValue).length == 0 && showList">Nenhuma sugestão
        encontrada</p>
    </ion-list>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
:host {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;

  > div {
    width: 100%;
    ion-input {
      width: 100%;
      padding-right: 50px !important;
    }

    ion-button {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      z-index: 2;
    }

    ion-list {

      position: fixed;
      box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
      border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
      overflow: auto !important;
      ion-item {
        z-index: 100;
        --full-highlight-height: 0;
      }

    }
  }
}
```

I am using the component inside an ion-item in the main page html.

Please help!

Comment: Hello! Could you create a Stackblitz demo with your code, please? That way it would be easier for us to take a look at the issue and see how to fix it. You can use **[this starter](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5-starter-app)** if you want :)

Comment: I tried but it doesn't recognize ionic tags. Also there are so many custom components on these screens. How do I make it recognize ionic components? Maybe I can make a Stackblitz of a simpler version without most components

Comment: Is the overlapping element `ion-button`?

Comment: No. It is a ion-textarea